# Facebook Connect using IE8 causing problems; any workarounds?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, facebook

I've been wrestling with problems using Facebook Connect on IE8 and i've reached a dead-end it would seem:

We have a Facebook game (Canvas iFrame) which had problems reported when using IE8. We've followed the instructions on the [FB.init](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.init/) developer page exactly, but got nowhere.

We tried using the channelUrl fix and various kinds of fixes all as outlined [here](http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?id=61389).

Our response headers are sending the P3P header:

```
P3P CP="IDC DSP COR ADM DEVi TAIi PSA PSD IVAi IVDi CONi HIS OUR IND CNT"
```

We also tested async and sync versions of this integration, neither yielded any differences in outcomes.

In spite of all our efforts, on IE8, FB.getSession() always returns an undefined value. There is plenty of information I have reviewed, though disappointedly had no success, in the bug reported to [Facebook](http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=10273) which they resolved as not a bug... despite ongoing reports of the issue from users on the thread long after they considered it resolved.

In a last ditch attempt I'm turning to here, and start with a sanity of an test FB app which has nothing contained within it except the FB.init JS example added with some console logging to show that the FB.getSession has got a uid.

If you are replying to this, please can I ask that you are checking this against ***IE8*** and are looking at the console, which on a successful load of the FB session will write

```
FB: [object Object] FB.getSession().uid: [your fb id]
```

http://apps.facebook.com/fb-js-issue

The code there is as follows:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">

    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {

        FB.init({
            appId: 'appId',
            status: true,
            xfbml: true,
            cookie: true,
            channelUrl: "http://ourserver.com/channelUrl.htm"
        });
        FB.Canvas.setAutoResize();
        console.log("Running FB test");

        setTimeout(function() {
            console.log("FB: " + FB + " FB.getSession().uid: " + FB.getSession().uid);
        }, 5000);


    };
    (function () {
        var e = document.createElement('script');
        e.async = true;
        e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
        document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
    }());

</script>
```

So by and large that sample app works fine, though in rare case even that has problems.

Our real apps (which use the same FB.init method) consistently suffer FB.getSession undefined problems on IE, thus fail to load

[http://apps.facebook.com/party-on](http://apps.facebook.com/party-on?st1=Dev&short_unique_tag=10000004)

**UPDATE** : We have determined that the problem more severely affect IE8 on Windows XP or Vista - IE8 on Windows 7 seems to be less problematic (although not 100%)

**How to get past this?**

So.. given that the problem seems pretty common and no fix is clear, short of some serious magic which hasn't yet been discussed publicly which will finally fix this issue, what would be really instructive would be highlighting other possible ways to integrate with FB.connect other than the one they show

The reason I mention this is when you look at how CityVille and FarmVille do their FB integration it's nothing remotely close to what FB themselves author as developer docs.. Hmm, interesting

Any fresh ideas and different angles would be massively welcomed at this stage!!

Comment: I just came across this: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/503 and wondered whether or not this could possiblty be to blame for the problems being experienced

Comment: Possibly related to other similar problems being reported: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6113212/facebook-connect-login-popup-window-postbacks-with-no-error

Comment: Facebook still have this as an open error http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=16842

Comment: Just a hint: You should use the current protocol for channelUrl (and the link within the channel-file), too.

Comment: Did you try policy files? http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?pid=156383#p156383 It helps me once, when I had problems with posting feeds on wall from app.

Comment: Did you set your Site Domain in your FB Application settings (App Settings -> Website).  I was having the same symptoms when i realized my site domain was not set. After setting it and clearing all cookies the issue was resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Just a random question, are you really using IE 8 in IE 8 mode? Be careful, because sometimes IE 8 flips to compatibility mode (IE 7) and then you're dealing with a whole new set of issues. This code on your page forces IE to render in the latest version. It needs to be the very first meta tag.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" >
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288325(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: That was meant to be a comment not an answer. Gotta figure this Stack thing out.

Answer (score 1):

I solved a similar problem adding async load after body tag

```
<body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
</body>
<script>
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId : 'yourAppId', 
      status : true, 
      cookie : true,
      xfbml : true,
      frictionlessRequests : true
    });

    FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow();
    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.statusChange', yourCode); 
};
(function(d){
     var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
     ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
}(document));
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

try removing all `console.log()` calls in your entire app.

Answer (score 0):

Have just spent ages trying to work out why my Facebook app was not working in IE8 but was fine in other browsers. The symptoms were that FB.init seemed to be called ok, but in the subsequent call to FB.getLoginStatus(callback) the callback just wasn't being called in IE8 (WinXP).

I eventually fixed it by uninstalling 'Google Chrome Frame' from IE8. Disabling it in the IE add-on manager was not enough, I had to uninstall it completely through control panel. It had been installed to allow GMail to be viewed in IE8, and the cynic in me thinks that Google probably don't mind too much if that breaks FB. The plugin also seemed to prevent IE8's javascript debugger from loading FB pages, which made it extra hard to work out what was going on...

Anyway, thought I'd share the info here in case anyone else has a similar problem.